# Is the fault with my PC likely to be my power supply?

Tags: windows, boot, power-supply

So I recently transported my PC to my new flat and after delays in being able to move in, it meant my PC was sat around in my van for about 3 days. Since setting it up and trying to start it, Its not been working.

When I push the power button, the fans start whirring and the LEDs light up, but there is no display output, it doesn't even show a bios splash screen, just nothing.
Frustratingly I began testing everything one by one with a second PC to try determine the cause of fault, swapped my RAM and my graphics card into another PC but all was fine.

I hope it's not my processor, but I haven't been able to check that as my other PC has an AMD compatible motherboard, however I'm told it's likely to be my PSU or possibly even my motherboard.

Based on my symptoms and the scenario with traveling after which my issue occured, is anyone able to suggest where my problem may lie? And can anyone tell me a way in which I could test my PSU to confirm its outputting enough power and isn't a bust?

I'm just trying to save myself money by replacing the wrong part, thanks in advance.

Comment: Any answer to this is a guess.

Comment: Does it make any sequence of beeps on startup? Systems often do, and they are designed to give an indication of the error.

Answer (score 2):

A kill-awatt (http://www.p3international.com/products/P4400.html) or a multimeter ([https://www.amazon.com/AstroAI-Digital-Multimeter-Volt-Diode/dp/B01ISAMUA6/ref=sr_1_3/130-3642137-4405951?ie=UTF8&qid=1504632059&sr=8-3&keywords=voltmeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ISAMUA6)) might do the trick to test the supply - here is a guide to testing PSU with multimeters (https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-manually-test-a-power-supply-with-a-multimeter-2626158).

Depending on where you live, a tool library, makerspace, or even a public library or city hall will lend you one of these at low or no cost (Where I live this is the case). The same makerspace might have folks who ae willing to help you tinker on this.

But, it's true as stated above, you're hazarding a guess here. Sounds like dust, vibration, jostling, or a difference in the places you're plugging in to could all be to blame.